# Numpy fromfunction type error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, lambda

I am trying to generate a numpy array from "fromfunction" function.

```
arr = np.array(([1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]))

def test(ii, jj):
   p0 = np.sum(arr[0:ii,0:jj])
   u0 = np.sum(np.arange(0, ii) * np.sum(arr[0:ii, 0:jj], axis=1)) / p0
   return u0

result = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: test(i,j), (2, 2),dtype=float)
```

This gives a type error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index, which comes due to the fact, it passes ii and jj as strings. After explicitly converting it to integers, it have an error "Only size 1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars". I guess it sends the indices as a vector.

```
result2 =  np.array([test(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]).reshape((3,3))
```

The above approach works but it is quite slow when applied to bigger arrays. Does anyone know how result can be modified to make np.fromfunction work?

I need to apply a function like this to a big 2D array.

Comment: `fromfunction` is not any sort of iterator.  It just makes `ii` and `jj` arrays, and passes them whole to your function (just one call).  Your `test` expects scalar values (the `0:ii` expressions).  `fromfunction` is just a convenience tool, not a performance one.  Given your `test`, there isn't a way of improving on the list comprehension.

Comment: A couple of things you could have done - read the `function` description in `fromfunction` more carefully.  Printed `ii` and `jj` in `test` to see what is actually being passed.  Look at the python code from `fromfunction` (it's quite short).